# Coral Trend Indicator how to Convert to Lvl5 Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

there is This Piece of code i found, **in Pine Script**. About **Coral trend indicator** but it is in a very old version. (version 2)

there is this Function `nz` which replaces NaN values to zero and that function discontinued for all I could understand so far so that i have searched (i am a rookie coder Tbh :( )

if you could give **ideas** on how to **change the formula** (regarding `nz`) i could **work around the rest myself**, i would really appreciate it.

here it is the code i am talking about :

```
//@version=2
study(title="Coral Trend Indicator", shorttitle="CTI", overlay=true)
src=close
sm =input(21, title="Smoothing Period")
cd = input(0.4, title="Constant D")
ebc=input(false, title="Color Bars")
ribm=input(false, title="Ribbon Mode")
di = (sm - 1.0) / 2.0 + 1.0
c1 = 2 / (di + 1.0)
c2 = 1 - c1
c3 = 3.0 * (cd * cd + cd * cd * cd)
c4 = -3.0 * (2.0 * cd * cd + cd + cd * cd * cd)
c5 = 3.0 * cd + 1.0 + cd * cd * cd + 3.0 * cd * cd
i1 = c1*src + c2*nz(i1[1])
i2 = c1*i1 + c2*nz(i2[1])
i3 = c1*i2 + c2*nz(i3[1])
i4 = c1*i3 + c2*nz(i4[1])
i5 = c1*i4 + c2*nz(i5[1])
i6 = c1*i5 + c2*nz(i6[1])


bfr = -cd*cd*cd*i6 + c3*(i5) + c4*(i4) + c5*(i3)
bfrC = bfr > nz(bfr[1]) ? green : bfr < nz(bfr[1])  ? red : blue

tc=ebc?gray:bfrC

plot(ribm?na:bfr, title="Trend", linewidth=3, style=circles, color=tc)
bgcolor(ribm?bfrC:na, transp=50)
barcolor(ebc?bfrC:na)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='Coral Trend Indicator', shorttitle='CTI', overlay=true)

src = close
sm = input(21, title='Smoothing Period')
cd = input(0.4, title='Constant D')
ebc = input(false, title='Color Bars')
ribm = input(false, title='Ribbon Mode')
var i1 = 0.
var i2 = 0.
var i3 = 0.
var i4 = 0.
var i5 = 0.
var i6 = 0.

di = (sm - 1.0) / 2.0 + 1.0
c1 = 2 / (di + 1.0)
c2 = 1 - c1
c3 = 3.0 * (cd * cd + cd * cd * cd)
c4 = -3.0 * (2.0 * cd * cd + cd + cd * cd * cd)
c5 = 3.0 * cd + 1.0 + cd * cd * cd + 3.0 * cd * cd
i1 := c1 * src + c2 * nz(i1[1])
i2 := c1 * i1 + c2 * nz(i2[1])
i3 := c1 * i2 + c2 * nz(i3[1])
i4 := c1 * i3 + c2 * nz(i4[1])
i5 := c1 * i4 + c2 * nz(i5[1])
i6 := c1 * i5 + c2 * nz(i6[1])


bfr = -cd * cd * cd * i6 + c3 * i5 + c4 * i4 + c5 * i3
bfrC = bfr > nz(bfr[1]) ? color.green : bfr < nz(bfr[1]) ? color.red : color.blue

tc = ebc ? color.gray : bfrC

plot(ribm ? na : bfr, title='Trend', linewidth=3, style=plot.style_circles, color=tc)
bgcolor(ribm ? bfrC : na, transp=50)
barcolor(ebc ? bfrC : na)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).